# How to std::move class with std::vector<class> member into another vector<class>?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

I'm trying to linearize a hierarchy of 'Node' classes into a single (std::vector) array. This is a complete c++ program code demonstrating the problem, minimalized as much as I think is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node;

struct B{
    int nvar1;
    std::vector<Node> Children;
};

struct Node{
    B bvar1;
};

void Linearize(Node & NODE, std::vector<Node> & ArrayOfNodes){
    std::cout<<"Linearizing started.\n";
    ArrayOfNodes.push_back(std::move(NODE));
    Node & node = ArrayOfNodes.back();
    for(int n = 0; n < node.bvar1.Children.size(); n++){
        std::cout<<"Running loop "<<n<<" of "<<node.bvar1.Children.size()<<"\n";
        Linearize(node.bvar1.Children[n], ArrayOfNodes);
    }
    std::cout<<"Done with node linearization.\n";
}


int main(){
    Node ParentNode;

    //Fill the ParentNode
    ParentNode.bvar1.nvar1 = 0;
    ParentNode.bvar1.Children.resize(2);
    ParentNode.bvar1.Children[0].bvar1.Children.resize(2);
    ParentNode.bvar1.Children[0].bvar1.Children[0].bvar1.nvar1 = 1;
    ParentNode.bvar1.Children[0].bvar1.Children[1].bvar1.nvar1 = 2;
    ParentNode.bvar1.Children[1].bvar1.nvar1 = 3;

    std::cout<<"I do get to the linearizing.\n";
    std::vector<Node> ArrayOfNodes;
    Linearize(ParentNode, ArrayOfNodes);

    std::cout<<"I do get to the displaying part.\n";
    for(int n = 0; n < ArrayOfNodes.size(); n++){
        std::cout<<ArrayOfNodes[n].bvar1.nvar1<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This crashes the program. The output until the crash is:

> I do get to the linearizing.
>   Linearizing started.
>   Running loop 0 of 2
>   Linearizing started.
>   Runnning loop 0 of 2
>   Linearizing started.
>   Done with node linearization.
>   Done with node linearization.
>   Running loop 1 of 18446744073709191157
>   Linearizing started.
>   Running loop 0 of 1011712
>   Linearizing started.

I'm trying to get an elegant and efficient solution here. The 'Node' class can get large and contains many other classes and vectors. Given the data size, I'm reluctant to construct move constructors/assignments to cover all that data structure.

What I want to do would work with this code:

```
void Linearize(Node & NODE, std::vector<Node> & ArrayOfNodes){
    std::cout<<"Linearizing started.\n";
    ArrayOfNodes.push_back(NODE);
    Node & node = ArrayOfNodes.back();
    for(int n = 0; n < NODE.bvar1.Children.size(); n++){
        std::cout<<"Running loop "<<n<<" of "<<node.bvar1.Children.size()<<"\n";
        Linearize(NODE.bvar1.Children[n], ArrayOfNodes);
    }
    std::cout<<"Done with node linearization.\n";
}
```

But that would copy stuff, when I want to move it. I want it to be more efficient than this.

Basically two question(s/ groups):

1. If default move constructer is called, why aren't the Nodes moved properly to ArrayOfNodes? Doesn't the default move constructor call the move constructor of every member, and std::vector has pointers inside anyway, so it should still point to the same data when moved? What part of the process am I misunderstanding?
2. What would be a standard/good/veteran coder solution to this kind of situation (linearization)?

Any and all comments welcome, this is my first question, if I'm doing something wrong or could just do better, tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see anything in there that I would deserve the downvotes for though. I hope I won't need to take my questions somewhere else :/

Comment: _"I don't see anything in there that I would deserve the downvotes for though."_ The missing [MCVE] for starters?

Comment: Alright, thank you for pointing me in a direction, I will look into improving that and update the question!

Comment: Moving does not preserve the object pointer. You are moving the stuff inside a node into a different node in the vector. Thus pointers to the old node dangle.

Comment: Also, when you do push_back, the std::vector could reallocate its array, invalidating all pointers to items you store in it. You'd have to pre-allocate a vector with enough elements to contain all nodes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo First, thanks for responding! I think I see it now, why my example is problematic. Now I only need to find a solution better than what I already have with copying. As for the pointer warning, I have no pointers to the nodes in the new vector, neither in the example (unless I'm ignorant about something) nor my original code prior to the vector being fully constructed (and then staying that way). But thank you for the warning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Does the update fix the problem? If so, I will proceed in the same way for any potential future questions.

Comment: @bead-v Oh, wow, I thought you kept pointers to the children because that's such a common way of doing it... I've never seen a tree built this way! :)    So when you move a child out of its parent and into the big vector, then how do you access a child from its parent? You loose all hierarchy information. If so, you probably want to empty the vector of children nodes after you've moved out the children. Sounds like they're off to college...

Comment: I'm not sure about this, did you try to std:move the node into the Linearize function? The function signature would be Linearize(Node && NODE, ...). (Sorry, I don't have backticks on my phone, so can't do proper formatting here).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The Node class has an index, which I can use to find any Node from the array. The hierarchy is not very important in my program, I need it preserved (in the indexes), but easily running through all nodes is more important to me. Also, tried to std::move into the function, same problem.

Comment: Ah! Now I see it. You take a reference to node, then push_back its children. The push_back triggers reallocation of the array, invalidating the reference (a reference is just a pointer with different syntax). Try pushing the child nodes first, then the parent node! (Or, as I suggested earlier, pre-allocating the std::vector.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes! Pre-allocating did the trick! Apparently, my understanding of references is lacking, I didn't realize they would be affected as well! Thank you so much!

Comment: @bead-v I'm glad that's solved. I've written up a full answer because that's easier for other people to see than some comments hidden underneath the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that `node` is a reference (i.e. pointer) to an item in the `std::vector` that you are constructing. After taking the reference, you use `push_back` on the vector, which will grow the underlying array and hence might invalidate all pointers to it (growing the array often means a new, larger memory block is allocated and all data is moved to it). When you then want to access the next child of the node, you are referencing freed memory.

There are 3 ways to solve this. First, pre-allocate the array before starting the linearization process:

```
std::vector<Node> ArrayOfNodes;
ArrayOfNodes.reserve(numberOfNodes); // <-- you need to be able to determine this
Linearize(ParentNode, ArrayOfNodes);
```

A second solution would be to push the children on the vector before you move the node:

```
void Linearize(Node & NODE, std::vector<Node> & ArrayOfNodes){
    std::cout<<"Linearizing started.\n";
    for(int n = 0; n < NODE.bvar1.Children.size(); n++){
        std::cout<<"Running loop "<<n<<" of "<< NODE.bvar1.Children.size()<<"\n";
        Linearize(NODE.bvar1.Children[n], ArrayOfNodes);
    }
    ArrayOfNodes.push_back(std::move(NODE));
    std::cout<<"Done with node linearization.\n";
}
```

A third solution would be to not take a reference to the node in the vector, but to take its index:

```
void Linearize(Node & NODE, std::vector<Node> & ArrayOfNodes){
    std::cout<<"Linearizing started.\n";
    size_t index = ArrayOfNodes.size();
    ArrayOfNodes.push_back(std::move(NODE));
    for(int n = 0; n < ArrayOfNodes[index].bvar1.Children.size(); n++){
        std::cout<<"Running loop "<<n<<" of "<<ArrayOfNodes[index].bvar1.Children.size()<<"\n";
        Linearize(ArrayOfNodes[index].bvar1.Children[n], ArrayOfNodes);
    }
    std::cout<<"Done with node linearization.\n";
}
```

A totally different approach would be to not move the nodes at all, but to construct a `std::vector<Node*>`, and fill it with pointers to the nodes. But that might not be what you're after.